# error al insertar registro PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola amigos de StackOverFlow tengo un problema al momento de realizar un registro con un foreach, la verdad soy muy reacio de preguntar me gusta investigar hasta dar con la respuesta pero estaba vez estoy muy atorado al momento de insertar datos con foreach
la insersion la probe con la db y los datos se insertan de forma correcta.

Mi tabla

```
 describe dt_ventas;
 +-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | id_dtventas     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | id_ventas       | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
 | id              | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
 | precio_unitario | float   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | cantidad        | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | descargado      | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 +-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Sentencia cuando registro los datos
INSERT INTO dt_ventas(id_dtventas, id_ventas, id, precio_unitario, cantidad,
descargado) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1', '200', '1', '0') ;

Cuando hago la insersion los datos si se registran en la db:

```
 SELECT * FROM dt_ventas;
 +-------------+-----------+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
 | id_dtventas | id_ventas | id   | precio_unitario | cantidad | descargado |
 +-------------+-----------+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
 |           7 |         1 |    1 |             200 |        1 |          0 |
 +-------------+-----------+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
```

Pero cuando hago lo mismo con foreach no se registra ningun dato :,v

Mi codigo de php es el siguiente.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <?php 
  include_once("template/header.php");
  include_once("controls/connect.php");
  include_once("controls/config.php"); 
  include_once("carrito.php");
 ?>

 <?php 

 if( isset($_POST) ) {

$total= 0;
//devuelve una clave de la sesion
$sid = session_id();
 $email=  $_POST['email'] ;
foreach($_SESSION['carrito'] as $indice=>$producto) {

         //total
         $total= $total+($producto['precio']*$producto['cantidad'] ) ;

        }

        $qry = $dbh->prepare ( "INSERT INTO ventas(
                                id_ventas, 
                                claveTransaccion, 
                                paypalData, 
                                fecha, 
                                email, 
                                total, 
                                status ) VALUES (
                                                 NULL, 
                                                 :claveTransaccion,
                                                 '', 
                                                 NOW(), 
                                                 :email, 
                                                 :total, 
                                                 'pendiente' ) " );

        $qry->bindParam(":claveTransaccion", $sid);
        $qry->bindParam(":email", $email);
        $qry->bindParam(":total", $total);

        $qry->execute();
        //recupera el ID de ventas
        $idVenta = $dbh->lastInsertId();
        //echo $dbh->lastInsertId();
        

        //DT_EVENTAS
        foreach($_SESSION['carrito'] as $indice=>$producto) { 

            $qryr = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO dt_ventas( id_dtventas, id_ventas, id,
 precio_unitario, cantidad, descargado ) 
                                  VALUES (NULL, :id_ventas, :id, :precio_unitario,  
:cantidad, '0' )") ;

            //recupera el ID de ventas e inserta los datos en la tabla
            $qryr->bindParam(":id_ventas", $idVenta);
            $qryr->bindParam(":id", $producto['id']);
            $qryr->bindParam(":precio_unitario", $producto['precio']);
            $qryr->bindParam(":cantidad", $producto['cantidad']);
            $qryr->execute();

        }
     
    echo "<h2>{$total}</h2>";

    /*NULL '1'. '1', '200', '1', '0' */
```

}

?>

eh intentado poner otro nombre las tablas y nada cambiar de variables cambiar de nombre etcetera y no mas no puedo encontrar la solucion jaja >:v. Acepto cualquier sugerencias, cambios en el codigo de todo.

Comment: lol nose que hice pero ya funciona nose porque rayos cuando pregunto aqui vuelvo a editar mi codigo y funciona cambie las variables de $qryr a $qry pero me extrana que anteriormente habia realizado eso y no funcionaba, cia talvez ? XD

Comment: No descarto lo dicho era la insersion que habia hecho de testing en la db :,,,v

Comment: lol ya lo resolvi por eso no me gusta preguntar porque me da pena quedar como noob y luego auto solucionar mis errores fck.

Comment: Ahora solucionado mi error me dispondre a ver la trilogia de el señor de los anillos. :v

Comment: O respondes tu propia pregunta (aclarando el problema y la solucion) o borras la pregunta, ya que no tiene respuesta...

Comment: Tienes un problema muy serio: eres demasiado *optimista* programando. Parece contradictorio, porque el *optimismo* es algo a lo que muchos aspiran. Pues el *optimismo* en programación es gravísimo. La tarea de un programador es ser lo más pesimista posible, es decir, pensar en todo aquello que pueda salir mal, no para lamentarse de ello, sino para resolverlo. En tu código, varias cosas pueden salir mal y no controlas ninguna de ellas. Por eso el código falla en algunos contextos, en otros no y tú piensas que el problema se resolvió por arte de magia. Pues eso, controla los errores en el código

Comment: Vaya que buen consejo, gracias me has dado un nuevo enfoque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigos de StackOverFlow me disculpo de antemano por no escribir mi respuesta antes,eh estado bastante ocupado estos dias. La verdad es que el problema estaba bastante facil de solucionar pero no me di cuenta hasta que me puse en modo serio, resulta
ser el que el problema estaba en la ultima coma jaja.
por esta razon no se registraban los datos. Ahora tengo un problema con paypal y su api pero eso es cuento para otra historia...

```
  //DT_EVENTAS
    foreach($_SESSION['carrito'] as $indice=>$producto) { 

        $qryr = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO dt_ventas( id_dtventas,             
                                id_ventas, id, precio_unitario, cantidad,   
                                descargado ) 
                              VALUES (NULL, 
                                      :id_ventas, :id, 
                                      :precio_unitario,  
                                      :cantidad, 
                                      '0' )") ; //Aqui tenia una coma XD

        //recupera el ID de ventas e inserta los datos en la tabla
        $qryr->bindParam(":id_ventas", $idVenta);
        $qryr->bindParam(":id", $producto['id']);
        $qryr->bindParam(":precio_unitario", $producto['precio']);
        $qryr->bindParam(":cantidad", $producto['cantidad']);
        $qryr->execute();

    }
 
 echo "<h2>{$total}</h2>";
```

Comment: Ahora me dispondre a ver la trilogia del hobbit.